# How do i cut a hole into a mesh?

Tags: mesh

As you can see i added three torus shapes to the center of the model but i would like to cut out the insides of those torus to leave circles in them how can i do this?[image]

Comment: I recommend you watch this video. It will give you ideas for your current problem and other issues in the future: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA

Comment: Unfortunately this question has been closed as a duplicate, while the answer to the duplicate question is not sufficient for your question. First of all, select a face of every torus by shift-right click. Keep pressing Ctrl-numpad + until all torus shapes are completely selected. Press P -> selection to seperate the torus shapes from the object. Go to the modifier panel, and add a boolean modifier. Set operation to union and object to the new torus object. Go to object mode and apply the modifier. Go back to edit mode, where you can select and delete the necessary faces to create a circle.